# How to get numbers out of a 2D array to a 1D array

Tags: javascript

I have an argument that passes me a 2D array and I want to get the numbers from that array and put them on a normal array.

The argument passed to me = ([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])
What I want to do = [1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1]

Thanks in advance, I think I'm having a brain fart over here!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) previous question should help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the array and add all data in new array with `concat()` method.

```js
var arr = [[1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]];
var newArr = [];


for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    newArr = newArr.concat(arr[i]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Also worked, just had to use it with [...arguments] on my case! Thank you

Comment: I think I didn't upvote at the time because I wasn't able to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `flat` method of Array!

```
const arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

console.log(arr.flat()) 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: This was really straightforward, just had to use [...arguments]! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use array flat method to convert 2d array to 1d array

```
const arr = [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6]
    ].flat(1); //flat(depth:Number)

console.log(arr);

// [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Worked without the depth, thanks